# Struggling with the use of a Comparator

Tags: java, comparator

The case: I have an ArrayList of objects, which has the following print method:

```
public void printAllItems()
{
    if(itemsList.isEmpty())
    {
        System.out.println("The list is empty");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Number of items: " + itemCount);
        for(ShopItem shopItem : itemsList) 
        {
            shopItem.printDetails();
            System.out.println();   // empty line between posts
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to sort those objects Alphabetically by one of their fields(`itemName` and of course its suitable `getItemName()` method). I went through the Java doc and found that I should use Comparator. The thing is that I didn't actually understood how to implement the Comparator code into the for-loop. Any suggestions ?

P.S. I am sorry, if the question looks awfully easy, but I am still a beginner and I get confused easily :(

Comment: You wouldn't put the Comparator in the for loop, it would go before it. Also I think you can just do `shopItem.Sort(itemName)`

Comment: You don't implement it with the `for` loop; you sort the collection first (using [`Collections#sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort) and then iterate through (using `for` loop). Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property), it has lots of examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering `getItemName()` returns a String, add this before the loop:

```
Collections.sort(itemsList, new Comparator<ShopItem>(){
                     public int compare(ShopItem i1, ShopItem i2){
                         if(i1 == null || i2 == null)
                              return 0; //do properly nullable handling
                         return i1.getItemName().compareTo(i2.getItemName());
                     }
                  });
```

Answer (score 1):

**Before** printing the collection, you can do:

```
Collections.sort(itemsList, new Comparator<ShopItem>() {
    public int compare(ShopItem i1, ShopItem i2) {
        return i1.getItemName().compareTo(i2.getItemName());
    }
});
```

Here I'm using an *anonymous implementation* of the `Comparator` interface.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a class implementing `Comparator` (or an anonymous class). You have it well explained in the [Comparator.compare](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare%28T,%20T%29) docs.

That is the approach described in the accepted answer.

I'd still like to post the Java 8 approach:

```
    itemsList
    .stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(ShopItem::getItemName))
    .forEach(item -> {
        item.printDetails();
        System.out.println();
    });
```